# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1/2) + (-1)^{n}}{n}$ converges or diverges?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How to check if the series $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(1/2) + (-1)^{n}}{n}$$ converges or diverges?

When $n$ is odd, series is $\sum \frac{-1}{2n}$

When $n$ is even, series is $\sum \frac{3}{2n}$

This series is similar to the series 
$$\sum \frac{-1}{2(2n-1)} + \frac{3}{2(2n)}$$

$$= \sum \frac{8n-6}{8n(2n-1)}$$
Which is clearly divergent.
So, the given series is divergent.

Is this method right?
Please, suggest if there is some easier way.

Comment: Your method is not correct. You distinguish $n$ even and $n$ odd for the partial sum not for the general term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**hint**

$$\sum \frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

is convergent by  alternate criteria.
$$\frac 12\sum \frac 1n$$
is a divergent Riemann series.

The sum of a convergent and a divergent series is a Divergent one.

Comment: The sum should diverge. Right?

Comment: @Mathsaddict Yes of course. but Div +Div  could converge.

Answer (score 3):

The idea is correct, but not correctly expressed. Asserting that the given series converges is equivalent to the assertion that the sequence$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{\frac12+(-1)^n}n\right)_{N\in\mathbb N}$$converges. If it does, then the sequence$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^{2N}\frac{\frac12+(-1)^n}n\right)_{N\in\mathbb N}$$converges too. But it follows from your computations that it doesn't.

Comment: From my computations, sequence of partiat sum diverges, and so does the series.

Comment: You write as if that's different from what I wrote.

Comment: I thought you are pointing towards some mistake in my calculations, since you wrote 'but' in the last line. Does your answer support my method to check if the series converges?